# htaccess: Remove "folder" permanently with 301

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Although I have worked through other entries with the same theme I was not able to find a solution for my particular problem.

Right now my URL-structure is like
www.abc.com/in/something/bla
I changed some settings and removed the /in/, now the URL-structure is
 www.abc.com/something/bla

I want to redirect permanently to the new structure.

None of the solutions I found @stackoverflow and in the web worked for me, therefore I paste (parts of) my htaccess-code beneath. It works perfectly except for the removal of /in/.
Thanks in advance for helping me out!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Enable Rewrite Engine
# ------------------------------
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# Redirect index.php Requests
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/system/.*
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

# Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# remove trailing slash
# 05.10.2012
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$  /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mod_alias:

```
Redirect 301 /in/ /
```

Using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^/?in/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

You'll want to put those close to the top, just under your `RewriteBase`

Comment: Thanks, the second solution works! Could you explain in short what's the difference between mod_alias and mod_rewrite in this case? I mean: Is one of them "better" than the other?

Comment: @BNetz One isn't better than the other, they're just 2 different modules that happen to have a bit of overlapping functionality. Mod_alias is used to map URI paths to file paths as well as redirect. Mod_rewrite changes URI-paths in a somewhat programmatic/conditional manner, and also has the ability to redirect. In your case, the mod_rewrite solution probably works better because when you have both aliases and rewrites, they can interfere with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/in/.*
RewriteRule ^/in(/?.*)$ http://${HTTP_HOST}$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Maksym, but this does not work for me. The /in/ is removed, but the CMS throws a 404-error. Most probably this is something special about my CMS. Thanks anyway!